# Removing unused master slide of multiple PowerPoint files using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I wish to remove unused master slides from multiple PowerPoint presentations.
The list of files is in an Excel file.
I wrote a macro that opens each PowerPoint file.
I found a macro that used within PowerPoint VBA removes unused master slides but doesn't work when I include it in my Excel macro.
Also I don't manage to save and close each PowerPoint file.

Macro that loops through files:

```
Sub Opennremove()

Dim myPresentation As Object
Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Set myPresentation = CreateObject("Powerpoint.application")

'Find last row of path files list
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Looping through files
For i = 1 To lastRow
    
    'Defines pwp file to open
    DestinationPPT = Cells(i, "A")
    'opens pwp file
    myPresentation.presentations.Open DestinationPPT
    myPresentation.Visible = True
    
    'Then I would like to : remove unused master slide, save, close
    
Next i

End Sub
```

Macro that works when used directly in PowerPoint:

```
Sub SlideMasterCleanup()

Dim k As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim oPres As Presentation
Set oPres = ActivePresentation
On Error Resume Next
With oPres
    For k = 1 To .Designs.Count
        For n = .Designs(k).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts.Count To 1 Step -1
            .Designs(k).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(n).Delete
        Next
    Next k
End With

End Sub
```

How could I:

- remove master slide in my Excel macro
- save and close each PowerPoint file before going to the next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a first shot at revising your code.  Give it a try; if it works, great. If not, let us know what went wrong, and on what line of code. Use this ONLY on a copy of your presentation(s).  I don't see where you've coded any way of determining whether a layout is used or not.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()

Dim myPresentation As Object
Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.application")

'Find last row of path files list
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Looping through files
For i = 1 To LastRow
    
    'Defines pwp file to open
    DestinationPPT = Cells(i, "A")
    'opens pwp file
    Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open(DestinationPPT)
    myPresentation.Visible = True
    
    'Then I would like to : remove unused master slide, save, close
    Call SlideMasterCleanup(myPresentation)
    
Next i

End Sub

Sub SlideMasterCleanup(oPres As Presentation)

Dim k As Integer
Dim n As Integer

On Error Resume Next
With oPres
    For k = 1 To .Designs.Count
        For n = .Designs(k).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts.Count To 1 Step -1
            .Designs(k).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(n).Delete
        Next
    Next k
End With

oPres.Save
oPres.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: First of all thank you so much for taking the time. I always work in a "test environnement" to prevent any damage ;)
When I run this code I have an error : 
Compile error : user-defined type not defined

This happened for the first line of the second macro "Sub SlideMasterCleanup(oPres As Presentation)"

If this can be of any help, I write my code in module of the VBA app not in the "sheets".

Comment: You're welcome (for the time) and wise (for using a test environment). ;-)

Comment: I Edited my comment (press enter by mistake) in order to tell you more about the error

Comment: Sorry ... my mistake. I forgot that you were running the code from Excel rather than PowerPoint. Change that line of code to Sub SlideMasterCleanup(oPres as Object)

Comment: Dear Steve, 
When I run your code I have an error : Compile error : user-defined type not defined This happened for the first line of the second macro "Sub SlideMasterCleanup(oPres As Presentation)" If this can be of any help, I write my code in module of the VBA app not in the "sheets".

Thanks again :)

Comment: @S.Tessier It looks like I may have been replying to your earlier question at the same time as you were writing a new one. Have you seen my reply starting with "Sorry ..."?

Comment: Dear Dear Steve,

I just saw your message! It works. Thank you so much for your help. Wish you a very nice day!